# CPU Maximum Frequency stuck at 59%

Tags: windows-7, performance, cpu, cpufreq

I have just installed a Windows 7 32-bit on my HP Compaq nx6310 notebook. However, once I boot into Normal Mode, I receive 2 Kernel-Processor-Power Event ID 37 warnings in my event log indicating that the performance of my processor is being limited by system frimware but this does not happen on Safe Mode.

Additionally, when I open the Resource Monitor to check my CPU Usage, I notice that the Maximum Frequency is always stuck at 59% instead of 100% and the system is very slow. In Safe Mode, this is always 100% and the system is fast.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uQtH.png)

[image: new user pic help]

What can I do to get a 100% Maximum Frequency on the Normal Mode as well?

Here are my system specifications:

- RAM: 1024 MB (1 GB) of RAM
- Processor: Genuine Intel(R) CPU T2300 @ 1.66 GHz Dual Core (Centrino Duo)
- VGA: Mobile Intel(R) 945 Express Chipset Family (WDDM 1.0)
- HDD: 160 GB
- System Model: Compaq nx6310

Comment: Did you check this while on battery power or when the power brick was plugged in? (Many laptops limit CPU speed when on battery power).

Comment: @Hennes I always use the AC power as I don't have any batteries equipped. The BIOS does not have any options for power saving or how I control the processor (except for toggling dual core)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've fixed this by overclocking as I noticed that the multiplier decreased to 6 instead of 11, so I set it back to 10 and it's now 99%.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was EIST (Enhanced Intel(R) Speedstep Technology) which throttled my CPU speed to avoid high temperature. I found out that it was a software driver which is located at **%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\intelppm.sys**. I renamed this driver and restarted, then I was able to get 100% Maximum Frequency (The temperature raised from 50 C to 60 C however)

Answer (score 0):

Its your power settings that is affecting your CPU performance, i have encountered exactly the same problem with my Fujitsu P series laptop. the CPU clock freq was locked at 0.78GHZ and i was worried i tried every thing from reinstalling the drivers to updating the drivers. But i finally found out that i just needed to press a physical button on my laptop to switch back my PC from power saver to high performance mode.

Comment: This appears to be an answer to a different question.